# getting users' friend list failed in fb API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

```
$fbuser = $facebook->getUser();
if ($fbuser) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
        //echo json_encode($user_profile);
    }
```

I can get users' profile data, but within it I don't see any friends. I tried  `'/me/friendlists'/` but doesn't work. I'm using graph API 1.0.

Comment: /me/friends gives you the friends

Comment: @WizKid it work! does that require permission?

Comment: Yes it requires user_friends permission

Answer (score 2):

You're fine to use the graph API 1.0 till April 30th, 2015, so beware!

Have you enabled a user access token for the "read_friendlists" permission your app?  If not, you can apply for this permission for your app within the status & review page in your app page @ https://developers.facebook.com

See below for a quote from the page from [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v1.0/user/friendlists):

> Permissions
>
> A user access token with read_friendlists permission is required to view the current person's >friend lists.